# CSS Grid A column to take as much space as possible whilst the other is variable

Tags: html, css

Using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid), this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I've tried with:

```
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 10%;
}
```

But that `10%` might still be smaller, depending on the content that's on that column. How can I make it as small as possible whilst being a width-variable field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) by using `max-content` or `min-content`.

```
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto max-content;
}
```

> **max-content**
>
> Is a keyword representing the largest maximal content
>   contribution of the grid items occupying the grid track.
>
> **min-content**
>
> Is a keyword representing the largest minimal content contribution of
>   the grid items occupying the grid track.

See [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).